# jquery deferred fallback - possible scoping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I am trying to listen to an array of deferred requests for completion. I want to add in fallbacks so that if the initial url fails, then it will load a json file. (I've loaded the jsbin page here to stop any cross domain issues).

My original code was something like

```
function makeCalls() {

        var deferreds = [];

        var statsDeferred = 
            $.get("http://thiswillfail.yesitwill");

        statsDeferred.fail(function() {
          $.get("http://run.jsbin.com/")
                    .done(function() {
                         statsDeferred.resolve();
                    });

        deferreds.push(statsDeferred);

        return deferreds;
    }


var deferreds = makeCalls();

$.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
            alert("done");
        });
```

However it fails at the line `statsDeferred.resolve();`

http://jsbin.com/pofejotu/1/

I have tried adding in $.proxy calls to maintain scope but it isn't working.

```
function makeCalls() {

        var deferreds = [];

        var statsDeferred = 
            $.get("http://thiswillfail.yesitwill");

        statsDeferred.fail($.proxy(function() {
          $.get("http://run.jsbin.com/")
                    .done($.proxy(function() {
                         statsDeferred.resolve();
                    }, this));
            }, this));

        deferreds.push(statsDeferred);

        return deferreds;
    }


var deferreds = makeCalls();

$.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
            alert("done");
        });
```

http://jsbin.com/vonibuhe/1/edit

Both fail on

```
statsDeferred.resolve();
```

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to chain promises, the correct method to use is `.then()` :

```
function makeCalls () {
    var statsDeferred = $.get("http://thiswillfail.yesitwill");

    statsDeferred = statsDeferred.then(
        null, /* on success, keep the initial promise's state */
        function(){ return $.get("http://run.jsbin.com/"); }
    );

    return statsDeferred;
}
```

---

```
statsDeferred.resolve();
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The error you have is the difference between a `Deferred` and a `Promise`.

- a `Deferred` exposes methods to change its inner state (`.resolve` and `.reject`),
- a `Promise` only allows you to consult this state, and react on it (`.done`, `.fail`, ...)

API functions will generally return a `Promise`, so that external users cannot meddle with the expected state. As an example, one way to "fix" your code would be the following :

```
function makeCalls() {
    // make a deferred, you will be the one in control of its state :
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var firstGet = $.get("http://thiswillfail.yesitwill");
    firstGet.done(function(response) { deferred.resolve(response); })

    // if the first request fails, run the second :
    firstGet.fail(function(){
        var secondGet = $.get("http://run.jsbin.com/");
        secondGet.done(function(response) { deferred.resolve(response) };
        secondGet.fail(function() { deferred.reject() });
    });

    // only return the Promise to the outer world :
    return deferred.promise();
}
```